# How to make inner join on parent field in Django

Tags: django

For data models shown as below, given the product_name, how shall I do a query with Django ORM to get objects containing "distance, city name, price" sorted by distance, price?

```
###  models.py ###
class Province(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()

class City(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()
    distance = models.IntegerField()
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)

class Price(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField()
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

*Same price apply to all cities within a province*

Answer (score 0):

You can access data this way:

```
cities = City.objects.all().order_by('distance')
```

Then you can, for example, create a list of dictionaries, and use it in the template the same way you use a queryset object:

```
cities_list = [{'city_name': city.name, 'distance': city.distance, 'price':Price.objects.get(province=city.province)} for city in cities]
```

Or, iterate over the cities:

```
for city in cities:
    city_name = city.name
    distance = city.distance
    price = Price.object.get(province=city.province)
```

Comment: I see, I can do that, but are you sure you need that if you can just use: ```City.objects.raw('SELECT c.name, c.distance, p.price FROM City AS c INNER JOIN Price AS p ON c.province=p.province WHERE p.product_name LIKE '%keywords%' ORDER BY c.distance, p.price') ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was expecting a ORM queryset to get the result, which was equivalent to SQL query: SELECT c.distance, c.name, p.price FROM City AS c INNER JOIN Price AS p ON c.province=p.province WHERE p.product_name LIKE '%keywords%' ORDER BY c.distance, p.price
It might have higher performance because it just hits the database just for once, and flexible to adjust the order fields as well as doing aggregation.

Comment: Thank you Andrey. Is there ORM query to do so rather than RAW SQL? I will go with raw sql if there is no alternative solution.

Comment: Please try this: ```City.objects.prefetch_related('province__price_set').filter(province__price__product_name='keyword')```

Comment: Your answer might work! While I am not quite clear on how to export the result after using "prefetch_related" and reverse related object, so I haven't verified it yet. Could you please give a short example? Inspired by your answer, I gave the field "province" in table "Price" a related_name "price_province", changed the query to "...prefetch_related('province__price_province')....". Query ran without problem. Then tried to export the price by: print(city.province.price_province.price), then got: AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'price'

Comment: city.province.price_province is like a ModelManager, it means you can iterate over it and filter it. For example ```[object.field for object in city.province.price_province.filter(field='keyword')]```

Comment: It does not work. If city=City.objects.prefetch_related('...').filter(...) is your case, running "city.province.whatever..." will report error: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'province'.